# Limit spanning of hline like cline

Tags: tables

Is there a way to limit the length of a hline, so that it behaves like a cline?
What I want to achieve is to have the the double lines you will get, when calling `\hline` twice.

What I basically want is the following table without the first 'box' (7C0, 3700, 11111000000). And that the top, left, and bottom border of that column/row is removed.

[image: sample table]

Basically this MWE without the top and left border.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|r|l|}
  \hline
  & hexadecimal \\
  & octal \\ \cline{2-2}
  & binary \\
  \hline \hline
  1984 & decimal \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only want the bottom half of the double line to extend to the first column you can use

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r|l|}
  \hhline{~|-}
  & hexadecimal \\
  & octal \\ \cline{2-2}
  & binary \\
  \hhline{-:=}
  \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{1984} & decimal \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r|l|} \cline{2-2}
  & hexadecimal \\
  & octal \\ \cline{2-2}
  & binary \\
  \hline \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{1984} & decimal \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad explanation. I wanted the bottom border of the first `hline` removed as well. David Carlisle's answer is what I wanted, though I didn't explaine correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with only the package `array`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|l|}
\cline{2-2} 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & hexadecimal \\
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & octal \\
\cline{2-2} 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & binary \\
\cline{2-2} 
\noalign{\vspace{\doublerulesep}}
\hline
1984 & decimal \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]